# Hibernate sessionFactory creation and weblogic datasource interaction

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, datasource, sessionfactory

i saw a lot of example of using hibernate, in particular the session Factory, programmatically
I used this:

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration()
                .configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

but in my current project i need some different implementation so i removed the FINAL for the sessionFactory constant and i implemented a constructor in order to inizialize this when it is null.

so i have an hibernateUtil abstrac class whit only the SYNCHRONIZED method buildSessionFactory and an implementation class whit this constructor

```
public myHibernateUtil(){
        if (mySessionFactory == null){
            mySessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
```

Is it safe?? In your opinion by removing the FINAL for the session factory it is possible to have problem with the number of session and saturate the datasource??

I make this question because i'm getting a strange error for weblogic:

Pool myDatasource is Suspended, cannot allocate resources to applications..

Thanks to all!

EDIT:
Into the Server1-diagnostic.log there are those exception :

[2014-05-21T18:46:41.428+02:00] [Server_1] [NOTIFICATION] [DFW-40101] [oracle.dfw.incident] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 356fce390f623850:-983a53a:1461f7d7cb4:-8000-0000000000000b1e,0] An incident has been signalled with the incident facts: [problemKey=BEA-337 [WebLogicServer] incidentSource=SYSTEM incidentTime=Wed May 21 18:46:41 CEST 2014 errorMessage=BEA-337 executionContextId=356fce390f623850:-983a53a:1461f7d7cb4:-8000-0000000000000995]
[2014-05-21T18:46:42.927+02:00] [Server_1] [NOTIFICATION] [DFW-40104] [oracle.dfw.incident] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 356fce390f623850:-983a53a:1461f7d7cb4:-8000-0000000000000b1e,0] [errid: 84] [detailLoc: /app/oss/bea-domains/osssbdomain/servers/Server_1/adr/diag/ofm/osssbdomain/Server_1/incident/incdir_84] [probKey: BEA-337 [WebLogicServer]] incident 84 created with problem key "BEA-337 [WebLogicServer]"

Moreover i found a lot of error like this in the server1.log:

Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '127.0.0.1', port: '7333'
in the communication beetween oracle service bus and my app.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you log in to the admin console -> Data Sources -> myDatasource -> Monitoring tab and test the data source? What errors are thrown in your server log file? Is it only the client/app that is having a problem?

Comment: i edit my post in order to give the Server1.log and Server1-diagnostic.log